# Dynamic allocation/deallocation of array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

[Via stackoverflow threads like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17569578/1655492), I discovered that you could use an array of pointers to manage a 2D array. In the past I used to use pointer to pointer to store 2D arrays, but now I have a requirement to store my data in contiguous memory, so pointer to pointer format doesn't work anymore.

A raw 2D array is an alternative to array of pointers, but raw 2D array doesn't work for me because I want to be able to allocate storage in the heap and not on the stack because my container can be very large and I might encounter stack overflow if I use vanilla 2D array.

My question is about how memory is allocated for array of pointers. I use `new` operator like below (see my constructor) to allocate my array of pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename DataType, unsigned numRows, unsigned numCols>
class Container2D {
    public:
        Container2D() {
            m_data = new DataType[numRows][numCols];
        }
        
        ~Container2D() {
            delete [] m_data;
        }
        
        DataType* getData() { return &m_data[0][0]; }
    
    private:
        DataType (*m_data)[numCols];
    
};


int main() {
    
    Container2D<int, 3, 3> container;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Does `new DataType[numRows][numCols]` allocate the entire 2D array on the heap or does it allocate `numRows` pointers on the heap while allocating `numCols` objects of type DataType on the stack?

In a pointer to pointer scenario (where I'd define my storage as `DataType** m_data`), I know for a fact that both dimensions of my array are allocated on the heap and I would call `delete m_data[i]` for each column and then call `delete[] m_data` to free my row data. In the array of pointers scenario, I'm not sure if my destructor above is freeing up data correctly.

Comment: The standard doesn't require implementations to have a stack or heap - but, yes, the entire 2D will (on systems using a heap) be allocated on the heap.

Comment: One way to free you self from these worries is to use a 1D contiguous array and implement the 2D index to 1D index mapping instead.

Comment: No such thing as "heap" memory in standard C++ but `new`/`delete` do use heap on systems that have a heap. Instead of using a pointer and `new`/`delete`, try using a suitable standard container.  `std::vector<std::vector<DataType> >` can be used to represent a 2D array if contiguity of rows/columns doesn't matter, and `std::vector<DataType>` (with suitable mapping of indices) can be used if contiguity matters. The default allocator for `std::vector` uses `new`/`delete` (so, if you follow basic guidelines to use `std::vector` correctly) will correctly manage/release memory (e.g. avoid leaks)

Comment: Or use a `std::unique_ptr<std::array<std::array<T, numCols>, numRows>>` - [example](https://godbolt.org/z/rKdPo1KEd)

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use a `std::vector` to manage your memory?

Comment: @Peter: I wasn't aware that the standard doesn't mandate usage of heap for dynamic memory allocation. I had assumed using the new operator meant that heap was used for allocating the memory requested. On systems where heap is not used does the standard guarantee that there won't be a stack overflow?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: array of array doesn't work because I need my data to be stored in a contiguous block of memory. My code interfaces with a library that expects a pointer to be passed to this data and will access the data by incrementing the pointer.

Comment: @Di9gitalEye  The standard doesn't use the term "heap" or "stack" in regard to memory at all.    The standard is hardware neutral and the origins of heap and stack (in regard to memory, at least) are related to particular hardware architectures (heap and stack were labels applied to memory implemented using distinct electronic circuits).  Not all hardware architectures have memory areas of heap or stack at all.

Comment: @DigitalEye I see. The data _is_ contiguous with an array of array, but it won't have the right type for what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a 1D contiguous array and implement the 2D index to 1D index mapping instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

template<typename DataType, unsigned numRows, unsigned numCols>
class Container2D {
    public:
        Container2D() { m_data = new DataType[numRows * numCols]; }
        ~Container2D() { delete [] m_data; }
        inline DataType  operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) const {
            assert( 0 <= i && i < numRows);
            assert( 0 <= j && j < numCols);
            return m_data[i*numCols+j];
        }
        inline DataType& operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) {
            // same as above, but this allows inplace modifications
            assert( 0 <= i && i < numRows);
            assert( 0 <= j && j < numCols);
            return m_data[i*numCols+j];
        }
    private:
        DataType* m_data;
};


int main() {
    
    Container2D<int, 3, 3> container;
    int x = container(0,0);  // retrieve the element at (0,0);
    container(1,2) = 9;      // modify the element at (1,2);
    // int y = container(3,0);  // triggers assertion errors for out-of-bound indexing
    
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- If `numRows` and `numCols` do not change for a specific class instance, `new` and `delete` are not necessary in this case. If they do dynamically change, it is better to store them as member variables instead of template parameters. If `numRows` and `numCols` are too large, one can dynamically allocate `Container2D` objects as a whole.
- As @GoswinvonBrederlow commented, there is no difference between this and `new m_data[numRows][numCols]` in terms of memory layout, but this convention makes it easier to extend to higher dimensions.

Comment: I'd suggest to switch from `DataType* m_data;` to `std::unique_ptr<DataType> m_data;`, and/or to provide/delete copy and move constructors and assignment.

Comment: How is `new DataType[numRows * numCols];` better than `new DataType[numRows][numCols];`?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: I don't think one is better than the other. The former format allocates a single memory unit of size numRows*numCols and returns a pointer to it. The latter allocates an array of numRows pointers each of which can point to block of numCols items of DataType type.

Comment: @ihdv: "if numRows and numCols do not change for a specific class instance, new and delete are not necessary in this case." I assume you're recommending declaring m_data as ```DataType m_data[numRows * numCols] ``` if numRows and numCols are compile-time constants.  However, for very large values of numRows and numCols isn't there a risk that declaring a static array might overflow the stack?

Comment: @DigitalEye No, both allocate a single block of memory. The only difference is that in one case the compiler multiplies row * numCols for you and the other you have to do that yourself. Well, and the bound checking warnings the compiler can show for the later case.

Comment: @ihdv: ```int m[10000][10000]``` causes a segfault on my platform where as ```Container2D<int, int, 10000, 10000>``` works fine. Clearly, I risk overflowing the stack if give up new. Thoughts?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I don't mean one is better in this specific example. But this makes it easier to extend to higher dimensions.

Comment: @DigitalEye You can `new` the `Container2D` object as a whole.

Comment: @DigitalEye But then you have to `delete` it later and take care of copying and moving it. Here is an idea, lets put it in a wrapper that manages that for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Does new DataType[numRows][numCols] allocate the entire 2D array on the heap or does it allocate numRows pointers on the heap while allocating numCols objects of type DataType on the stack?

When you write

```
DataType arr[numRows][numCols];
```

the memory will be in one contiguos block as you mentioned. Nothing changes there when you use `new`. It will allocate one contiguos block of memory of the specified type. There is no hidden array of pointers into the real data.